# How to set Return-Path with mail();

Tags: php

How can I set "Return-Path" with php?

what i've tried

```
        $subject = "title \"" . $row['title'] . "\"";
        $headers = "From: test <no_replay@test.com>\r\n";
        $headers .= "Return-Path: no_replay@test.com\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

        mail($email,$subject,$addletter,$headers);
```

From gmail source I see `Return-Path: <apache@localhost.localdomain>`

Comment: Iirc you need to use `-f` sendmail option, and add the web server as trusted user to change From:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Windows **Return-Path:** should work. On linux you have to use the **-f** sendmail option for that. More info can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
mail($email,$subject,$addletter,$headers, "-fno_replay@test.com");
```

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks